# dropdown not updating from Knockout array

Tags: knockout.js

I am updating my Knockout object in Knockout and am verifying via the console that it is getting updated correctly.  But the dropdown is not getting refreshed with the new value.  If I refresh the page manually, the dropdown will be updated.  I think I need to make something observable, but not totally sure.

This is my KO viewmodel:

```
var SellerViewModel = function(groups) {
        var self = this;

        self.json = groups;
        self.groups = ko.computed(function() {
            var opts = [];
            for(var key in self.json)
            {
                if(self.json.hasOwnProperty(key))
                {
                    opts.push({Text: self.json[key].majorGroup + " / " + self.json[key].minorGroup, Value: self.json[key].groupId});
                }
            }
            return opts;
        });

        self.addGroup = function(json) {
            var group = JSON.parse(json);
            self.json.push(
                {
                    "ExtensionData":{},
                    "contractId":"10006",
                    "groupId":group.groupID,
                    "imageId":null,
                    "majorGroup":group.majorGroup,
                    "minorGroup":group.minorGroup
                }
            );
            console.log(JSON.stringify(self.json));
        };
```

And my HTML dropdown:

```
<select data-bind="value: roomID, options: $root.groups, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', optionsCaption: ' -- select a room --', disable: disableRoom" class="form-control" id="@roomID"></select>
```

And finally, this is how the dropdown gets populated on pageload:

```
var groups = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode(ViewBag.GroupDetail.SellerGroup) );
sellerViewModel = new SellerViewModel(groups);
```

Forgot to add one last snippet.  This is how I am adding an additional item into the knockout object, which is supposed to update the dropdown.

```
var json = '{"majorGroup" : "' + major + '", "minorGroup" : "' + minor + '", "groupID" : "' + groupID + '" }';
sellerViewModel.addGroup(json);
```

My guess is that self.groups needs to be an observable array.  But I don't know how to do that because I set it equal to ko.computed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pimbrouwers already mentioned, you need to make `json` an `observableArray` if you want the UI updated whenever the array changes.

```
self.json = ko.observableArray(groups);
```

---

You can make some improvements to your code. Instead of looping through indexes of `self.json` and checking `hasOwnProperty`, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
self.groups = ko.computed(function() {
    // if "json" is not an observableArray, then "self.json.map"
    return self.json().map(function(group) {
      return {
        Text: group.majorGroup + " / " + group.minorGroup,
        Value: group.groupId
      }
    })
});
```

---

And you are concatenating and forming a json in string format and then parsing it back. Instead, you could send an object itself.

```
var group = {
  majorGroup: major,
  minorGroup: minor,
  groupID: groupID 
}

sellerViewModel.addGroup(group);
```

And remove the `JSON.parse()` from the `self.addGroup`.

---

[Here's a **fiddle** for testing with all these changes](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ws79wn6z/)

You can also go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/3082296) to know more about the difference between json and javascript object literal

Comment: Thank you.  I kept getting those "undefined / undefined" added into my dropdown on pageload.  I was checking `self.json().length` right before right before the for loop in the computed function and it was 0, so I don't know why 7 of those were getting added.  But when I changed it to your map example above, that issue went away.  No idea!

Comment: @adiga you're completely right... I sincerely apologize, was having a bad morning and there was absolutely no reason to take this out on you. I will remove my previous comments out of respect. I also just want to mention that the rep-side of SA isn't the motivation. I find helping people in this fashion usually leads to a better conceptual understanding for me personally.

Comment: @pimbrouwers well, we have that in common. I learn a lot of stuff by going through the documentation and reading other answers. This is why I like knockout and asp.net-mvc tags because there aren't many [FGITWs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite) here to ruin all the fun :) Unlike say, javascript or c#.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem, with a simpler solution.

`self.json = ko.observableArray(groups);`

In order for your `computed` to fire, it needs to register a "subscription". Right now, you have it tied to just a normal JavaScript variable (by the look of the `push()` I'm guessing it's an array).

Making `self.json` an observable array will create this subscription for you.

Comment: I think you're right.  I must have something still not right in my code, my dropdown is getting populated with multiple "undefined / undefined" on page load.  I can't see where it is coming from though. That is happening after I added your code from above.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(groups);` if you place that as the first line in your view model?